# Is my postgresql backup correct to use it again

Tags: postgresql

I have created a Backup file, but the file is only a Data. Has no extension. Is that correct ? Or did I anything wrong?

I clicked on my table and press the backup button. Can I INSERT the table without problems in my database again?

Comment: Why don't you try? A backup that you didn't try to restore, is worthless anyway. Use pg_restore for an archive file or psql for a sql file. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html

Comment: You didn't give us any context. Where did you click? What client are you using?